# Scrolling Image using PixelWriter / Reader

Tags: image-processing, javafx

I'm trying to create a scrolling image that wraps around a canvas to follow its own tail. I've been trying to use PixelWriters and Readers to save off the vertical pixel lines that are scrolling off the screen to the West, and append these to a new image which, should grow on the RHS (East) of the screen.

It scrolls, but that's all that's happening. I don't understand how to calculate the scanlines, so apologies for this part.

Any help appreciated.

```
package controller;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import util.GraphicsUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

class ImageContainer extends HBox {
int w, h;
int translatedAmount = 0;
Image image;
Canvas canvas;
long startNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
WritableImage eastImage = null;

public ImageContainer() {
    setVisible(true);
    load();
    w = (int) image.getWidth();
    h = (int) image.getHeight();
    canvas = new Canvas(w, h);
    int edgeX = (int) canvas.getWidth(); //You can set this a little west for visibility sake...whilst debugging
    getChildren().addAll(canvas);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    canvas.setVisible(true);
    gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);
    setPrefSize(w, h);
    eastImage = new WritableImage(translatedAmount+1, h); //create a new eastImage

    new AnimationTimer() {
        public void handle(long currentNanoTime) {
            if (((System.nanoTime() - startNanoTime) / 1000000000.0) < 0.05) {
                return;
            } else {
                startNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
            }

            translatedAmount++;

            Image westLine = getSubImageRectangle(image, 1, 0, 1, h); //get a 1 pixel strip from west of main image
            PixelReader westLinepixelReader = westLine.getPixelReader(); //create a pixel reader for this image
            byte[] westLinePixelBuffer = new byte[1 * h * 4]; //create a buffer to store the pixels collected from the about to vanish westLine
            westLinepixelReader.getPixels(0, 0, 1, h, PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(), westLinePixelBuffer, 0, 4); //collect the pixels from westLine strip

            Image tempImg = eastImage; //save away the current east side image

            byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[(int)tempImg.getWidth() * h * 4];
            PixelReader tempImagePixelReader = tempImg.getPixelReader(); //create a pixel reader for our temp copy of the east side image
            tempImagePixelReader.getPixels(0, 0, (int)tempImg.getWidth(), h, PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(), tempBuffer, 0, 4); //save the tempImage into the tempBuffer

            eastImage = new WritableImage(translatedAmount+1, h); //create a new eastImage, but one size larger
            PixelWriter eastImagePixelWriter = eastImage.getPixelWriter(); //create a pixel writer for this new east side image
            eastImagePixelWriter.setPixels(1, 0, (int)tempImg.getWidth(), h, PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(), tempBuffer, 0, 4); //copy the temp image in at x=1
            eastImagePixelWriter.setPixels((int)tempImg.getWidth(), 0, 1, h, PixelFormat.getByteBgraInstance(), westLinePixelBuffer, 0, 4); //copy the westLine at x=tempImg.width

            image = getSubImageRectangle(image, 1, 0, (int) image.getWidth() - 1, h);
            gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0); //draw main image
            System.out.println(edgeX-eastImage.getWidth());
            gc.drawImage(eastImage, edgeX-eastImage.getWidth(), 0); //add lost image lines
        }
    }.start();
}

public void load() {
    Path imagePath = Paths.get("./src/main/resources/ribbonImages/clouds.png");
    File f = imagePath.toFile();
    assert f.exists();
    image = new Image(f.toURI().toString());
}

public Image getSubImageRectangle(Image image, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
    PixelReader pixelReader = image.getPixelReader();
    WritableImage newImage = new WritableImage(pixelReader, x, y, w, h);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    imageView.setImage(newImage);
    return newImage;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why make this more difficult than necessary? Simply draw the image to the `Canvas` twice:

```
public static void drawImage(Canvas canvas, Image sourceImage, double offset, double wrapWidth) {
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

    // make |offset| < wrapWidth
    offset %= wrapWidth;
    if (offset < 0) {
        // make sure positive offsets do not result in the previous version
        // of the image not being drawn
        offset += wrapWidth;
    }
    gc.drawImage(sourceImage, -offset, 0);
    gc.drawImage(sourceImage, wrapWidth - offset, 0);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Image image = new Image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/402px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg");
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(canvas));

    DoubleProperty offset = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    offset.addListener((observable, oldOffset, newOffset) -> drawImage(canvas, image, newOffset.doubleValue(), canvas.getWidth()));
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(offset, 0, Interpolator.LINEAR)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), new KeyValue(offset, image.getWidth()*2, Interpolator.LINEAR))
    );
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it when I get home. Some explanation would be nice. My solution was attempting to draw once, then only add the offset pixels; surely this would be quicker?